Crypttab timeout
I have Ubuntu 22.04.
I have no any strings about timeout= in my manual page (man crypttab).
However it is in manual on Internet (Crypttab).
Does it mean my crypttab not support timeout=?
Why I cannot find timeout= in my man page?

Perhaps the section ON DIFFERENT CRYPTTAB FORMATS and the reference to the systemd crypttab(5) manpage is relevant here?

@steeldriver I see, thank you. How can I call systemd crypttab(5) manpage from shell instead man crypttab?

sorry idk - I can't find any package that contains the systemd manpage (at least not in 22.04)
